# Better way to declare generic parameters on class

Tags: c#, class, generics, fluentvalidation

I'm writing a FluentValidation custom validator to validate that two read only collections have the same number of elements.

I'm using VS2022 and FluentValidation v11.5.2.

I current have the following:

```
public class CollectionSizesMatchValidator<T, TProperty, TElement> : PropertyValidator<T, TProperty>
    where TProperty : IReadOnlyCollection<TElement>
```

but I'm getting a CA1005 message: Avoid excessive parameters on generic types.

I thought this might be a better solution but it doesn't compile

```
public class CollectionSizesMatchValidator<T, IReadOnlyCollection<TElement>> : PropertyValidator<T, IReadOnlyCollection<TElement>>
```

I don't like the warning generated by the compiler, so I'd like to reduce the number of generic types. I thought I could use ICollection, but IReadOnlyCollection doesn't "inherit" from ICollection

When I use the validator I have to supply all the types.

Is there a better solution than the one I currently have?

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1005) says to avoid 3+ generic parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second attempt you need to specify `TElement` as generic parameter, not `IReadOnlyCollection<...>` and then use it for `PropertyValidator<T, IReadOnlyCollection<TElement>>`:

```cs
public class CollectionSizesMatchValidator<T, TElement> : PropertyValidator<T, IReadOnlyCollection<TElement>>
{
    public override bool IsValid(ValidationContext<T> context, IReadOnlyCollection<TElement> value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string Name { get; }
}
```

Or just disable the warning as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1005#when-to-suppress-warnings).